Falla de conexión a MySql desde el ejecutable generado en python por py installer
espero que se encuentren muy bien,en resumen, sucede que cuando genero cualquier ejecutable en python/pyinstaller con MySql embebido sucede que la conexión falla (cosa que no sucede cuando corre desde consola), arrojando el siguente error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "texto.py", line 29, in retornarListas
File "mysql\connector\pooling.py", line 322, in connect
File "mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 151, in init
File "mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 1426, in connect
File "mysql\connector\connection_cext.py", line 335, in _open_connection
RuntimeError: Failed raising error.
alguna solución?

Esto donde ocurre? cual es el codigo de la conexion donde falla?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
